# Width scrolling remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I don't want a width-scrolling bar on my website and wanted to know if you know whats causing it and how to fix it(code).

I already tried this:

```
 html, body {
        max-width: 100%;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't link to live sites in your question as the only source for a working example of your problem. Your question needs to remain useful after an answer is found, and if the only place where the problem is clearly demonstrated is fixed, then the question is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `div`  `row bg-about` have css `margin-right: -15px` just wrap the `row bg-about` in another div `.container-fluid` and everthing will works fine.

Tip.
You shoul always wrap `row` inside `container`, `container-fluid` or `col-*-*`

Answer (score 1):

The reason is this rule in your CSS:

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

It adds 30px the 100% width of `.row`

remove it...

Answer (score 1):

Your div with class `row bg-about` has a margin-right of -15px which causes your page to be larger than 100%.

Just remove the `row` class from this div and the problem should disappear.